# Can't add numbers at a specific index to a double in R

Tags: r, double

I want create 10 b1's for each value of x1 and x2's in xp and yp lists by optimizing res formula below. However my values are somehow not added to b1.created. I get b1.created = 0 when I check after I run the code.How can I make the code work?

```r
y <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,2,6,7,8,9,10),ncol = 1)
x1 <- matrix(c(2,4,6,5,10,12,14,16,18,20),ncol =1)
x2 <- matrix(c(1,4,9,16,25,25,48,64,81,99),ncol = 1)
x <- cbind(x1,x2)
created.b1 = 0
normal <- function(b0,y,xp,yp,x1,x2){for (i in xp){
  res <- sum((y- (b0 + x1[i]*xp[i] + x2[i]*yp[i]))^2)
  optobj <- optimize(normal,c(-10,10),y =y ,xp = xp,yp =yp, x1 = x1,x2 = x2)
  created.b1[i] = obtobj$minimum[i]
}
}
```

Comment: After defining `created.b1`, you created a function `normal`, but didn't even call it. Why do you expect that `created.b1` will be affected?

Comment: @yarnabrina I called it in optimizer function. I am pretty new to R, how else can I make the code work?

Comment: You will have to call `normal` on the arguments. I do not know what are the values you want to pass to it, and hence can't provide a solution. But I should point out that you have not defined `y1` anywhere, so probably you will face problems for it. And, you are also returning nothing.

Comment: @yarnabrina y1 should have been x2 I have provided all info necessary in the code for reproducibility.

Comment: What is `b0`? And, a point i missed before, do you intentionally call `normal` inside `normal`?

Comment: @yarnabrina b0 is the value I want to optimize the formula of  "res" Then from optobj$minimum I get the b0 value for that xp*x1 + yp*x2. The obtobj$minimum is the b0 value I am looking for. But it is a repeated process for each element in xp and x1 & yp and x2 we should get one b0 value. We will have 10 values of optimized b0 values at the end. I have the idea how to do this but I can't write the code properly so help would be extremely appreciated! I am updating the question to contain better details.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to find that value of intercept `b0` for which `res` is minimum subject to given `y`, `xp`, `yp`, `x1` and `x2`, and you want to repeat this 10 times for 10 choices of  regression coefficients `xp` and `yp`?

Comment: @yarnabrina yes you are right, that is exactly what I wanted to do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want, but please cross-check.

```
created.b1 <- numeric(length = 10)
for (i in 1:10)
{
    opt_obj <- optimise(f = function(b0, y, xp, yp, x1, x2) sum((y - (b0 + (x1 * xp) + (x2 * yp))) ^ 2),
                        interval = c(-10, 10),
                        y = y,
                        xp = xp[i],
                        yp = yp[i],
                        x1 = x1,
                        x2 = x2)
    created.b1[i] <- opt_obj$minimum
}
created.b1
```